# Spring Security 403 Error j_spring_security_login

Tags: authentication, spring-security, http-status-code-403, http-error

I had everything working fine the other day, but now when I go to login I get a 403 error saying the requested page is forbidden. The user is still successfully logged in, i.e. I can go back and gain access to the pages that are secure. There are not errors in the console.

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/main.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
<h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>
<c:if test="${param.error != null}">
   <p class="error">Login failed. Check user name and password.</p>
</c:if>
<form name='f'
    action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check'
    method='POST'>
    <table class="formtable">
        <tr>
            <td class="title">User:</td>
            <td><input  class="control" type='text' name='j_username'    value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Password:</td>
            <td><input class="control" type='password' name='j_password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<p><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/newAccount">Create a new account.       </a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**security-context.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"   
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">      


<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/adminPortal"
        access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/addDrug"
        access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/drugAdded"
        access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/addingDrug"
        access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/drugList"
        access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/userList"
        access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/doctorPortal"
        access="hasRole('doctor')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pharmacistPortal"
        access="hasRole('pharmacist')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/customerPortal"
        access="hasRole('customer')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newAccount"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accountCreated"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createAccount"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>
```

Login Controller
    package com.pharmacy.management.system.controller;

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.pharmacy.management.system.dao.User;
import com.pharmacy.management.system.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

private UserService userService;

@Autowired
public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String showLogin() {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping("/logout")
public String showLogout() {
    return "logout";
}

@RequestMapping("/newAccount")
public String newAccount(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "newAccount";
}

@RequestMapping("/accountCreated")
public String accountCreated(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "accountCreated";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/createAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAccount(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "newAccount";
    }
    user.setAuthority("doctor");
    user.setEnabled(true);

    if (userService.exists(user.getUsername())) {
        result.rejectValue("username", "DuplicateKey.user.username");
        return "newAccount";
    }

    try {
        userService.create(user);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        result.rejectValue("username", "DuplicateKey.user.username");
        return "newAccount";
    }
    return "accountCreated";
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
```

you write at last change sequence of it. put first of all other definition.

Comment: Not sure if it that would have worked, but will try in case I don't want to route all users to the same page. I solved the issue by setting the default redirect login and setting it to always enabled back to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Try do it as my configuration. The order url intercept order is very important:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <!-- HTTP security configurations -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"
            login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
        <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/choices/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/password/reset" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/account/create" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/account/activate" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/password/change" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/client/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    </http>
    <!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="SHA-256" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Not sure if it that would have worked, but will try in case I don't want to route all users to the same page. I solved the issue by setting the default redirect login and setting it to always enabled back to the homepage.